# Why does running manage.py runs calls in urls.py

Tags: django, manage.py

I've created Django application which runs TCP server in background. And everytime I run eg. `python manage.py migrate` or `python manage.py collectstatic` it turns on this TCP server and hangs in terminal, I need to Ctrl+C this to stop.
Is there any way to stop running this code when executing manage.py?
My code is placed in `urls.py` and the TCP server starts in a Thread.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

imports ...

start_big_tcp_server()
start_tcp_server()

urlpatterns = [
    paths...
]
```

Comment: what does the code in `urls.py` look like?

Comment: @HenryWoody, I've updated question